# User input with spaces (in batch)

Tags: batch-file

hello i'm making a basic text based adventure game in windows batch, i cant have spaces in user input.

my code is:

```
:quest1
cls
echo MUM: %PlayerName%, your breakfast is ready!!!
set /p PlayerInput1=">"

if %PlayerInput1%=="look around" echo you are in your bedroom upstairs in your house, in %PlayerHome%
```

with PlayerInput1 i want the user to input look around but when i try to run it it said:
around=="look around" was unexpected at this time

how do i fix this

Comment: Odd that you would put quotes around one side of the string comparison to protect the spaces but not the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:quest1
cls
echo MUM: %PlayerName%, your breakfast is ready!!!
set /p PlayerInput1=">"

if "%PlayerInput1%" =="look around" (echo "you are in your bedroom upstairs in your house, in" "%PlayerHome%")
```

You forget the quotes in  if "%PlayerInput1%", and echo don't need to be between() but is a good practice. *Thanks to [@Dennisvagils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5022761/dennis-van-gils) *

Comment: The parenthesis, although good practice, aren't needed on the same line.

Comment: Thanks @DennisvanGils for the tip

Comment: No problem. Btw, it would be best to update your answer frome "echo needs to be" to "it's better to"

Answer (score 1):

Put string between your variavle too :

```
set /p "PlayerInput1=^> "

if "%PlayerInput1%"=="look around" echo you are in your bedroom upstairs in your house, in %PlayerHome%
```